# Merge list items having more list and items

Tags: elixir

I am working on a list that happens to have such items

```
[
  %{localtions: [], doctors: [%{name: "Junaid", hospital: "west"}, %{name: "Farooq", hospital: "test"}]},
  %{localtions: [%{name: "Dom", address: "test"}, %{name: "Domi", address: "west"}], doctors: []},
  %{localtions: [], doctors: []},
  %{localtions: [%{name: "Dominic", address: "test"}, %{name: "DomDom", address: "west"}], doctors: []}
]
```

I am trying to convert it into this only.

```
[locations: [%{name: "Domi", address: "test"}, %{name: "Dom", address: "test"}%{name: "Dominic", address: "test"},  %{name: "DomDom", address: "west"}], doctors: [%{name: "Junaid", hospital: "west"}, %{name: "Farooq", hospital: "test"}]]
```

any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Update  [%locations:  to [locations:

Comment: why %{address: "test", name: "Dom"} in result is removed ?

Comment: you missed a colon sign in result section:  address: "test"}%{name: "Dominic",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this functions based on your need:

```elixir
t = [
    %{
      localtions: [],
      doctors: [%{name: "Junaid", hospital: "west"}, %{name: "Farooq", hospital: "test"}]
    },
    %{
      localtions: [%{name: "Dom", address: "test"}, %{name: "Dom", address: "west"}],
      doctors: []
    },
    %{localtions: [], doctors: []},
    %{
      localtions: [%{name: "Dominic", address: "test"}, %{name: "DomDom", address: "west"}],
      doctors: []
    }
  ]
```

the function is defined as:

```elixir
  def name_is_unique(l) do
    Enum.reduce(l, %{}, fn x, mp ->
      Map.merge(mp, x, fn _k, v1, v2 ->
        Enum.reduce(v1 ++ v2, %{}, fn x, acc -> Map.put(acc, x.name, x) end)
        |> Map.values()
      end)
    end)
  end

  def duplication_check(l) do # with duplication check
    Enum.reduce(l, %{}, fn x, mp ->
      Map.merge(mp, x, fn _k1, mpV1, mpV2 ->
        (mpV1 ++ mpV2) # [%{name: "Dom"}, %{name: "Dom"}]
        |> Enum.reduce(MapSet.new(), fn inerListMap, inerMapSet ->
          MapSet.put(inerMapSet, inerListMap) # %{name: "Dom"}
        end)
        |> MapSet.to_list()
      end)
    end)
  end

  def with_duplication(l) do
    Enum.reduce(l, %{}, fn x, mp ->
      Map.merge(mp, x, fn _k1, mpV1, mpV2 ->
        mpV1 ++ mpV2
      end)
    end)
  end
```

if your uniqueness is the `name` key then use `name_is_unique` or if you want full uniqueness over map items use `duplication_check` and don't care about duplication use `with_duplication`

```elixir
name_is_unique(t)
%{
  doctors: [
    %{hospital: "test", name: "Farooq"},
    %{hospital: "west", name: "Junaid"}
  ],
  localtions: [
    %{address: "west", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "west", name: "DomDom"},
    %{address: "test", name: "Dominic"}
  ]
}

duplication_check(t)
%{
  doctors: [
    %{hospital: "test", name: "Farooq"},
    %{hospital: "west", name: "Junaid"}
  ],
  localtions: [
    %{address: "test", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "test", name: "Dominic"},
    %{address: "west", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "west", name: "DomDom"}
  ]
}

with_duplication(t)
%{
  doctors: [
    %{hospital: "west", name: "Junaid"},
    %{hospital: "test", name: "Farooq"}
  ],
  localtions: [
    %{address: "test", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "west", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "test", name: "Dominic"},
    %{address: "west", name: "DomDom"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: name was a metaphor sorry, there can be some other values as well instead of name

Comment: I fixed the issue with other keys

Comment: i have updated the first data, please check it out.

Comment: Does %{address: "test", name: "Dom"} and %{address: "west", name: "Dom"} have difference ?

Comment: I updated the data again sorry for the confusion, the data will not be the same but all will be unique.

Comment: your welcome, I think f2 is works for you, test it

Comment: Hello, is it possible that you can remove MapSet? as there not going to be any duplicates

Comment: Added another function

Comment: goddamn this code is nasty, I would recommend to refactor to small recursive functions instead of those reduces.

Comment: But as I remember, It is recommended that we use functions such as fold and reduce instead of defining our return function.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
input_list = [
  %{
    doctors: [
      %{hospital: "west", name: "Junaid"},
      %{hospital: "test", name: "Farooq"}
    ],
    localtions: []
  },
  %{
    doctors: [],
    localtions: [
      %{address: "test", name: "Dom"},
      %{address: "west", name: "Domi"}
    ]
  },
  %{doctors: [], localtions: []},
  %{
    doctors: [],
    localtions: [
      %{address: "test", name: "Dominic"},
      %{address: "west", name: "DomDom"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Module:

```
defmodule Items do
  def sanitize(input_list),
    do: Enum.reduce(input_list, [localtions: [], doctors: []], &update_items(&2, &1))

  defp update_items([localtions: localtions_list, doctors: doctors_list], %{
         localtions: new_localtions,
         doctors: new_doctors
       }),
       do: [localtions: localtions_list ++ new_localtions, doctors: doctors_list ++ new_doctors]
end
```

IEX session:

```
iex()> Items.sanitize(input_list)
```

Result:

```
[
  localtions: [
    %{address: "test", name: "Dom"},
    %{address: "west", name: "Domi"},
    %{address: "test", name: "Dominic"},
    %{address: "west", name: "DomDom"}
  ],
  doctors: [
    %{hospital: "west", name: "Junaid"},
    %{hospital: "test", name: "Farooq"}
  ]
]
```